# how to make a user default option in android as in iPhone

Tags: android

in the first activity of my app i have created some fields as like a registration form and then it goes on to the other activities.  Once the user starts the app he must fill all those fields.

when the user closes the app and open's once again, now i should not diplay the registration activity. This must be done until the app is deleted from that device.

I came to know that in iPhone they have an inbuilt option called as User Default, how to create such a thing in ANDROID apps.

What is it called in android, pls explain me....if possible with a sample code or example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is it called in android

It is called "an if statement".

Your activities, in `onResume()`, can check if the user has registered by checking your database (or wherever you are storing the data). Then, *if* the user has not registered, those activities can call `startActivity()` to launch the registration activity.